# Zuul API Gateway monitoring

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, monitoring, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

Does Zuul have a web application to monitor API's?
Since Zuul is an API gateway.Does it has its own UI where we can monitor the API's ?How many requests received for a particular API? What was the request and response details?